# Read webpage content from URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a website in which the user will provide with URL of some other page and the code will read **(not open)** it and extract a part of the page.

Say, I provide URL for this page, and I get the question header of the page.

How can I do that.?

I tried using AJAX, creating object of `HTTPRequest`, but was not able to read a particular part of the page. (*say innerHTML of some #id*)

Comment: You have to use serverside script (PHP) to do that. You are not allowed to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: If the website you are making the request from is not on the same domain as the originating AJAX request, this will not work due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). You need to do the scraping on the server-side.

Comment: if on another domain you'll need to either scarpe from your server using whatever language server runs...or use a proxy service like YUI that will pull parts of a page and convert to jsonp

Comment: Are you aware of the Same Origin Policy? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy  You will most likely need to build a server-side proxy application that does this for you so you can call it on your own domain.

Comment: Read about the same origin policy.

Comment: Highly doubt users know how to provide you with css selectors need to scrape just part of a page

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Had I gotten 1$ each time this question was asked...

Comment: @gdoron Rory and I had a similar conversation recently and we agreed that he gets $1 for the same origin related questions and I get $1 the event delegation ones.  I'm handing my notice in later :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a php lib made for this and its called [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Syntax:

```
file_get_contents("URL");
```

Example:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```